# ggplot linetype by column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataframe

```
dt <-
  data.frame(
    date = c("2020-05", "2020-05", "2020-05", "2020-05", "2020-06", "2020-06", "2020-06", "2020-06"),
    type = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b"),
    sub_type = c("aa", "bb", "aa", "bb", "aa", "bb", "aa", "bb"),
    value = c(seq(1:8))
  )
```

I'd like to create graph from it in ggplot, color should be given by type column, linetype by subtype column. For some reason it wont work

> Error: geom_path: If you are using dotted or dashed lines, colour,
> size and linetype must be constant over the line

```
ggplot(dt,
  aes(
    x=date, 
    y=value, 
    group=sub_type,
    color=sub_type,
    linetype=type
  )
) +
  # geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you need to use the same variable for both `color` and `linetype`. If you want to use `linetype` and `color` for different variables, you need to put as `group` the interaction of both variables.

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x = date, y = value, group = interaction(type,sub_type), 
               color = type, linetype = sub_type)) +
       geom_point()+
       geom_line()
```

[image]